# How to hide rectangle outline while drawing curves

Tags: ios, swift, quartz-2d, ellipse

In my app I need to have a `UIView` whose form is initially a circle but then it can be altered into an ellipse by changing its height or width. So, I have overridden the `drawRect()` method like the following:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    if (self.isRound) {
        let ctx:CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0.5)
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, rect)
        CGContextStrokePath(ctx)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width / 2
    }
}
```

which works quite well, returning this result:

[image]

I would like to know how to hide, if possibile, those 4 corners so that only the ellipse itself is strictly visibile. Is there a way?

**UPDATE and SOLUTION**

This is the solution I have found, looking [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextFillEllipseInRect) in all Apple Core Graphics functions concerning ellipses. First of all, if my `UIView` is supposed to be an ellipse, in its constructor I take the following trick concerning alpha parameter:

```
if (self.isRound) {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.6, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.0)
    }
else {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.6, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.4)
    }
```

In this way the background rectangle is not showed at all. Then, this is my `drawRect()` method:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    if (self.isRound) {
        let ctx:CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0.0, 0.6, 1.0, 0.4) /*!!!*/
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, rect) /*use Fill and not Stroke */
        CGContextStrokePath(ctx)
    }
}
```

which gives me this result:

[image]

Comment: Obviously, it **is** possible, because you managed to draw that white circles without corners :) I think you can solve this problem by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You need a clipping path, have a look at `CGContextClip`